# How to convert application to run under Medium trust level?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, .net-3.5

My web application is composed of several Visual Studio projects. It currently runs fine under high trust level (`<trust level = "High" />`). When I try to run it under medium trust level, I get this error:

> Security Exception
>
> Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.
>
> Exception Details: System.Security.Security
>   Exception: Request failed.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> ```
> [SecurityException: Request failed.]
> System.RuntimeTypeHandle._GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark stackMark, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) +0
> System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark stackMark) +64   
> System.RuntimeType.PrivateGetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark stackMark) +58   
> System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +65   
> System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +342   
> System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +52
> ```
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4952; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4955

What is the best way to identify the problem and convert the application to run properly under medium trust?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've got some dynamic configuration resolution going on - have you got some custom Config Groups defined in your web.config - reflection is one of the first things that gets turned off in a medium trust environment, and most hosts will leave it off.

If so, I'd suggest moving over to creating an explicit [configuration section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsection.aspx) handler if possible.